# How to configure docker to exclusively access a private registry?

Tags: debian, docker

I keep images on a private registry. When docker pulls an image and it is  not found on the private registry it is instead fetched from the default docker registry.

How can one disable the default docker registry lookup ? I don't want to fetch images from the default docker registry at all.

I'm running on a debian hosts.

Answer (score 0):

One option/workaround I can quickly think of is to name/tag those images uniquely. E.g. if you tag it with your username

```
anovil@anovil-Latitude-E6440:~/tmp$ docker run nginx:itsafire
Unable to find image 'nginx:itsafire' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/nginx
Tag itsafire not found in repository docker.io/library/nginx
anovil@anovil-Latitude-E6440:~/tmp$
```

Or unique names

```
anovil@anovil-Latitude-E6440:~/tmp$ docker run nginx-itsafire
Unable to find image 'nginx-itsafire:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/nginx-itsafire
Error: image library/nginx-itsafire:latest not found
anovil@anovil-Latitude-E6440:~/tmp$
```

Let me know what do you think about this option/workaround

Answer (score 0):

Currently, its not possible to change the default registry. [see here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203)

You can use by using `URL` of private registry i.e.
1. First login to your private registry.

```
docker login https://myrepo:8080
```

2. after login you can pull

`docker pull myrepo:5000/myimage`

if you use the a redhat, we can use [--block-registery hostname](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/04/15/understanding-the-changes-to-docker-search-and-docker-pull-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-1/)

```
--block-registry hostname
```

But above yet not accepted.